Content Security Policy Integration for Java with React , Vite as build tool
I was trying to integrate the csp for the application. In this application I have React as the UI and Spring as the backend. I build the UI application using Vite and Gradle for Spring. I am facing the challenge of passing the nonce value to the UI dynamically.
String nonce = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        httpResponse.addHeader("Content-Security-Policy","default-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'none'; script-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data:; style-src 'self' "+nonce+"; font-src 'self'; connect-src 'self';");

This is sending back a response header by having a custom filter in my Java backend. It will create a unique string all the time for the nonce. Help me on how to get this value in the React frontend to be able to add this dynamically in index.html.
Thanks in advance
I used UUID version 4 to generate the random value which I set using the http response header in my custom filter.
I tried the Sha256 also but it will get changed if any update for the UI application is made. Not feasible.
Using the unsafe inline is also not a good choice.
My requirement is to fetch the nonce value in my UI application dynamically so that I can populate the nonce value in index.html to allow the inline execution of the style that are getting generated dynamically by the material UI.
